# Hosting a dynamic website on AWS with auto scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I am confused how to host a dynamic Laravel website on AWS. Currently, i have an **auto scale group** configured to **MIN 1** and **MAX 1**. What i'm trying to achieve is lunch a new EC2 server, when the current EC2 goes down.

What i don't understand is where should i store my website code to **enable the new EC2 server to obtain it automatically!** I have read about storing it in S3 bucket, but my website is dynamic, not sure if that is suitable.

Any guidance would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could copy the entire contents of /var/www/html and store it in an s3 bucket. 
Then you can add a bootstrap script in the ec2 instance that copies the contents of the s3 bucket to its /var/www/html directory.

Comment: This seems like the perfect solution. Can you provide any links, tutorials, or videos that can help me

Comment: You can find examples in the below course hosted on udemy and acloudguru. However they are paid courses.
AWS Certified Solutions Architect - Associate 2018 by  Ryan Kroonenburg

Comment: This is an amazing solution, but what do you do when your code changes? instance refresh?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any engine for cloud provisioning environments and applications like Ansible or [Urbancode Deploy Blueprint designer](https://developer.ibm.com/tv/vra-blueprint-designer-integration/) and configure deployment scripts there which may get the source/artifacts from the repository, artifactory server ([Jfrag](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/)) or wherever you want to get from.

Comment: can i do that with aws CodeDeploy?